# Need pythonic way to schedule one time jobs with arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, scheduled-tasks, cron

The premise is that I have a script which checks a resource every morning, and retrieves times and URI of events, which will vary from day to day.  I want to pass the time and URI location to a scheduler, so that a script designed to capture the event gets called at the event time, passing the location as a variable to the capture script.

At first glance crontab seems like the easiest way to do it, but every job is unique and will only run once, so it creates a lot of maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a suggestion for Python specifically, but given that you mentioned crontab as something you were considering, the "one-off" version of a crontab would be `at`.

- ['at' tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/one-time-task-scheduling-using-at-commad-in-linux/)
- ['at' man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at)